# Add Input to Each Column of HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an input field to each cell of my HTML table when I add a new row. The problem is that each time I click the button it only adds an input field to the first column. If I change the index number it only works for either the first or last column, but no columns in between.

```html
 <table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th id="item">Item</th>
    <th>Ounces (Oz)</th>
    <th>Grams (g)</th>
    <th>Fluid Ounces (FOz)</th>
    <th>Milliliters (mL)</th>
    <th>Drops</th>
    <th>Completed</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Click button to test funtionality.</p>
<button onclick="AddRow()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function AddRow() {
   // Get ID for table from HTML file
   var table = document.getElementById("table");
   // Count number of columns in table
   var columnNumber = document.getElementById("table").rows[0].cells.length;
   // Add row to last row in table
   var row = document.getElementById("table").insertRow(-1);
   // Create Input field in table
   var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
   newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
   newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Raw Good Name");
   newInput.classList.add("TableInput");
   // Add columns to new row matching header
   for (i = 1; i <= columnNumber; i++) {
      var firstColumn = row.insertCell(0).appendChild(newInput);
   }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the input or simplify the script

I made the HTML valid and use an eventListener as recommended

```js
const tb = document.getElementById("tb");
const columnNumber = document.querySelectorAll("#table thead tr th").length - 1;
const inp = '<td><input type="text" placeholder="Raw Good Name" class="TableInput"/></td>';
let cnt = 1;
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",() => {
  tb.innerHTML += `<tr>
    <td class="right">${cnt++}</td>
    ${[...Array(columnNumber).keys()].map(i => inp).join("")}
  </tr>`
})
```

```css
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="item">Item</th>
      <th>Ounces (Oz)</th>
      <th>Grams (g)</th>
      <th>Fluid Ounces (FOz)</th>
      <th>Milliliters (mL)</th>
      <th>Drops</th>
      <th>Completed</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody id="tb">
      </tbody>
</table>

<p>Click button to test funtionality.</p>
<button type="button" id="add">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be creating the `input` and appending it to the cell within the loop that creates the cells so that more than one will be created.

```css
/* This is only here for display purposes in the Stack Overflow environment */
input { width:5em; }
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th id="item">Item</th>
    <th>Ounces (Oz)</th>
    <th>Grams (g)</th>
    <th>Fluid Ounces (FOz)</th>
    <th>Milliliters (mL)</th>
    <th>Drops</th>
    <th>Completed</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Click button to test funtionality.</p>
<button onclick="AddRow()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function AddRow() {
   // Get ID for table from HTML file
   var table = document.getElementById("table");
   // Count number of columns in table
   var columnNumber = document.getElementById("table").rows[0].cells.length;
   // Add row to last row in table
   var row = document.getElementById("table").insertRow(-1);

   // Add columns to new row matching header
   // Loop should start at 0 and continue as long as you are less than
   // the array length
   for (i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) {
     // Create Input field in table
     var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
     // newInput.setAttribute("type", "text"); <-- Not needed: type="text" is the default
     // newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Raw Good Name"); <-- See following line for simpler syntax
     newInput.placeholder = "Raw Good Name";
     newInput.classList.add("TableInput");
     
     // If we're not on the first of last column
     if(i !== 0 && i < columnNumber - 1){
       newInput.type = "number"; // Make the input a number
     }
     
     row.insertCell(0).appendChild(newInput);
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also figured out I could do this with adding the element via HTML. But this seems more intuitive for what I was trying to do! Thank you!

Comment: Now, is there a way I can make the first and last column text input while the middle columns are number?

Comment: @TaylorLarrechea` Yes, just check the column index within the loop before you create the element and if the index isn't `0` or `columnNumber-1` (the first and last column indexes), set `newInput.type="number"`, otherwise, don't (since `type="text"` is the default). I'll update the answer to show this and consider marking this as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer.